# Using flexible file writer in Jmeter produces unwanted results in the output csv

Tags: jmeter, postman

I am using the flexible file writer in Jmeter to write the four variables that I have captured and defined in the properties file. I have used the debug sampler to verify and view results of the values of each of the 4 variables that I have used.
But when I am trying to use number of threads as more than 3 or 5, I am getting garbled and multiple values of the variables in the same column of the output csv as:
[image]

But ideally I am expecting the result to be like:
Timestamp_Queued|Timestamp_Download_Started|Timestamp_Download_Completed|Timestamp_Completed
1623596826050   1623596829514   1623596829868   1623596830045
1623596826195   1623596826434   1623596826840   1623596827071
1623596826427   1623596827736   1623596828138   1623596828319
1623596826629   1623596830096   1623596830417   1623596830600
1623596826809   1623596827113   1623596827514   1623596827692

Can someone help please. I have tried using other JS to capture the data one below the other but I am not able to capture the data in the above way. I am sure Jmeter must have an easy way to accomplish this.
Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I have spent a lot of time on this. Explored many different options on the internet but didn't find any proper solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you by looking at the screenshot of the result file, we need to see your configuration of the flexible file writer, know how do you launch your JMeter script, is there any suspicious entries in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), etc.

Given that:

1. You declare your variables as [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
2. Configure the Flexible File Writer to save these variables as `variable#0,variable#1,etc`
3. [Run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

You should get the anticipated results

More information: [Using the JMeter Flexible File Writer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Here are the variables used:
sample_variables= Timestamp_Queued,Timestamp_Download_Started,Timestamp_Download_Completed,Timestamp_Completed
This is the fields of flexible file writer in Jmeter UI mode:
Write File Header: Timestamp_Queued|Timestamp_Download_Started|Timestamp_Download_Completed|Timestamp_Completed

Record each sample has: variable#0|\t|variable#1|\t|variable#2|\t|variable#3|\r\n

You have mentioned in non-GUI mode I should run this. Can you clarify will it work in non GUI mode and not in the GUI mode?

Comment: Provide the desired path to the results file in the "Filename" field

Comment: Yup that I have provided. The path to a csv file. But still I am getting multiple and non systematic entries in the rows as per the screenshot.